# How to extend a class that is returning this in their methods

Tags: java, inheritance, libgdx

The question is easy but I'm not sure it's possible to do it...

if we have a class like

```
class A {
    private int foo;

    public A(int bar) {
       this.foo = bar;
    }

    public A setFoo(int bar) {
       this.foo = bar;
       return this;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
       return this.foo;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
       this.foo++;
    }
}
```

we can see that it's just simply a class with a private member and a setter/getter.
The interesting thing is, to allow method chaining, the setter is returning `this`.

So we can do things like this:

```
A a = new A(0);
a.setFoo(1).doSomething();
```

The problem here is when I try to extend that class add some functionality implementing an interface like this

```
class B extends A implements I {
    public B(int bar) {
        this.super(bar);
    }

    public void methodI() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

It seems ok, until I start using it like this

```
B b = new B(1);
b.setFoo(2).methodI();
```

Because `setFoo` is actually returning an instance of `A`, not an instance of `B`, and in A `methodI` doesn't exist...

Any workaround? Thanks.

By the way, I just wrote a basic code simply to understand, but if you want to know more, I'm just trying to extend the some of the basic classes of *libgdx* (like `Math.Vector2`, `Math.Vector3`) to implement *Poolable*.

Comment: Did you try casting? `((B)b.setFoo(2)).methodI()` ?

Comment: @Ori Lentz Yes, but I don't feel like doing casting everytime when it looks like there's a more natural answer. Of course I don't know if it's possible, so I'm asking before writing some dirty code :P

Comment: Why do you need vectors to implement Poolable? They don't need to implement that to be able to work with Pool, and typically you would always have some value to initially set it to when you obtain one, so there's not really a need for a `reset()` method. The reason I ask is, if there is a good reason, might as well add it to the source.

Comment: Tenfour04: You are right about overwriting its value and not needing a `reset()` method, but that's not the point of Poolable.
The main point for implementing Poolable is to avoid creating and destroying new objects and therefore calling the `gc` a lot. It's performance related.
Imagine a critical function calling 60 times per second where you are using Vectors as local variables. They will be created and destroyed evreytime, which maybe is ok for desktop, but it can be optimized in mobile games.

Comment: @danikaze you might be confusing Poolable with Pool. tenfour4 is correct, you don't have to implement Poolable to be able to work with a Pool. Implementing Poolable does not avoid creating and destroying new objects.

Comment: @Xoppa, mmm. Of course that Poolable creates and destroys objects, but it also reuses them. If you have a Pool of 16 Vectors, and you only are using at the same time 10 of them (just saying), you don't need to create any new Vector, or destroy them. And that's the whole point here.

Comment: No, that's the point of `Pool` not of `Poolable`. Or do you mean that you aren't using `Pool` at all and manually calling the reset method?

Comment: @Xoppa, from the libgdx wiki: *Object pooling is the principle of reusing inactive or "dead" objects, instead of creating new objects every time. This is achieved by creating an object pool, and when you need a new object, you obtain it from that pool. If the pool has an available (free) object, it is returned. If the pool is empty, or does not contain free objects, a new instance of the object is created and returned. When you no longer need an object, you "free" it, which means it is returned to the pool. This way, object allocation memory is reused, and garbage collector is happy.*

Comment: For using a `Pool` of objects, the objects need to implement the `Poolable` interface... so I don't see your point...

Comment: To phrase it differently: `Pool` can pool any type of object, not just the ones that implement `Poolable`. The only reason to implement `Poolable` is if you need a `reset` method to be called for clearing object references and possibly setting default values. And even setting default values is unnecessary if you are creating a specialized `Pool` subclass for handling your type of object, because you can set defaults using the `newObject` method.

Comment: There is also the `Pools` class for making your life super-easy for classes that have empty constructors and are not inner classes. You don't even need to subclass `Pool` because you can just call `Pools.obtain(Vector2.class)` and `Pools.free(vector2)` directly and it handles management of various pools for you behind the scenes via reflection.

Comment: Tenfour04, thanks! Didn't know you can have a Pool without implementing Poolable. So that's was my fault... but I guess I'm right about the reason of using a Pool (avoiding gc). And what I was doing was something like `new Pool<Vector2>()`...

Comment: anyways, apart from libgdx, the original question is still a legitimate java question... i.e. I want to extend Vector2 to have a constructor accepting a custom data type... or whatever...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class B can override the method setFoo and change the return type to B because B is a more specific version of A. An overridden method can have a more specific return type. e.g.

```
class B extends A implements I {
    public B(int bar) {
        this.super(bar);
    }

    public void methodI() {
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    public B setFoo(int bar) {
       this.foo = bar;
       return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the first solution I thought, or even re-implementing the class with copy-paste since I can't reuse it... but... was looking for a workaround so I don't have to rewrite lots of methods (If you take a look to the libgdx classes there a lot of methods in several classes like Vector2, Vector3, etc. It's not only the direct setters but also lot of methods to perform operations to modify the internal data of the real classes)

Comment: If you want to change the return type you have to override the method signature. But you could save some copy and paste by calling the supers instance of the method rather than re-implement. e.g.    @Override
    public B setFoo(int bar) {
       super.setFoo(bar);
       return this;
    }

Comment: Since I can't modify the code of the libgdx library since it's a jar (and probably because it won't be a good idea if it gets updated), I'll go with your answer and mark it as the valid one... but I also will try to make a pull request with the answer proposed by bedrin because I feel it's the "correct one"

Answer (score 2):

You should use generics here:

```
public class A<T extends A<?>> {

    public T self() {
        return (T) this;
    }

    private int foo;

    public A(int bar) {
       this.foo = bar;
    }

    public T setFoo(int bar) {
       this.foo = bar;
       return self();
    }

    public int getFoo() {
       return this.foo;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
       this.foo++;
    }

}

public class B<T extends B<?>> extends A<T> implements I {

    public B(int bar) {
        this.super(bar);
    }

    public void methodI() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to use such chained calls:

```
B b = new B(1);
b.setFoo(2).methodI();
```

Comment: Remember that I didn't created the A class, but it's already given.

Comment: Since I can't modify the code of the libgdx library since it's a jar (and probably because it won't be a good idea if it gets updated), I'll go with bhspencer's answer and mark it as the valid one... but I also will try to make a pull request with your answer because I feel it's the "correct one"!

Answer (score 1):

Have run into this before as well. Don't think there's a baked in simple solution. Consider overriding all setter methods:

```
class B extends A implements I {
    @Override
    public A setFoo(int bar) {
        super.setFoo(bar);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `public B setFoo`?

Comment: Yep, that's the first solution I thought, or even re-implementing the class with copy-paste since I can't reuse it... but... was looking for any workaround so I don't have to rewrite lots of methods (it's not only the direct setters but also lot of methods to perform operations to modify the internal data of the real classes)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (i.e. I do not consider this a *better* solution than the above, just may be appropriate) and certainly not an answer to the title of your question but a possible solution to your problem.

You could consider using `default` methods offered by Java 8. It is specifically for adding functionality to existing classes.

```
// From LibGDX Pool.Poolable
interface Poolable {

    public void reset();
}

// Class A untouched.
class A {

    private int foo;

    public A(int bar) {
        this.foo = bar;
    }

    public A setFoo(int bar) {
        this.foo = bar;
        return this;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        this.foo++;
    }
}

// Extend Poolable to add the functionality.
interface PoolableVector extends Poolable {

    default void reset() {
        // Not sure what you want to do here.
    }
}

// A Poolable A trivially made.
class B extends A implements PoolableVector {

    public B(int b) {
        super(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not very sure about this but... 1st of all, I think you can't use Java 8 with Android yet...
2nd, if you don't use default methods but implement reset in the B class I think you get the same result??? Which is trying to call B.doSomething on an A object returned by A.setFoo when calling b.setFoo().doSomething() as I explained in the question...
Correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score -2):

Just have setFoo() return void, and then you can do:

`B b = new B(1);
b.setFoo(2);
b.methodI();`

Comment: OP wants the "return this" feature

Comment: In that case I can just ignore the return value and do it in two different lines yes, but I was asking about a workaround to use that functionality...